# Internet explorer sending different user-agent strings to different sites

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, user-agent

I'm trying to track down a bug right now with a silverlight application. We are getting the browser info from the HtmlPage.BrowserInformation class, but it seems to be returning incorrect information. When running on IE9, the browser information says that it is running on version 8.0. I opened up Fiddler to see what was happening at the HTTP level, and here is what I'm getting for the user-agent strings to my test servers (the test servers run our own server software that uses WCF for HTTP requests):

> User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)

Here's the user-agent string when I go to any other site:

> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)

I'm not sure how the BrowserInformation class works (i.e., does all of its information come from the user-agent string, or from somewhere else). Any insights on this would be helpful.

Comment: Silly question, is the browser set to run in compatability mode on that site?

Comment: I've looked, and it appears that it isn't, but I don't know of a fool proof way to tell. Right now I'm pulling up the command bar, then going to the tools menu, then looking at the Compatibility View item, but it's grayed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question it is clear that you are not a IE user.

Tho resolve your issue you need to add this to all the pages:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

It is important to add it right after the head tag like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for pointing this out. You're right, I had no idea about using meta tags to force compatibility mode. The .html file we are using had the meta tag with IE=8 instead of edge. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks! You are not the first one that is thanking me for this particular resolution. This is not an obvious thing to find out yourself. Also we both should be thankful to Microsoft that they are doing everything to keep us occupied with this kind of nonsense.

Comment: For more information about IE's user agent string (and how it varies), see [the MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx).  To date, the article has been updated to reflect variations between versions.  While there's no guarantee it will continue to be updated, it's a good resource for historical reference.  (It's also a good illustration why browser detection is not a good practice.)